# Advice on unit testing a method with a disposable concrete third party dependency

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm creating a service that will serve as a facade for a third party toolkit we use.  The toolkit does not make much use of interfaces, and often requires using transient disposable classes.  Specifically, here is an example of a method that wraps an image loader:

```
    public RasterImage LoadImage(string fileName)
    {
        using (var codecs = new RasterCodecs())
        {
            return codecs.Load(fileName);
        }
    }
```

I'm not really sure how to make this testable. I thought about a factory to create the RasterCodecs, but since it doesn't have an interface, the factory method would have to just return the concrete class and I'm not sure how I could mock that.

Comment: As long as RasterCodecs isn't `sealed` you can generate an interface and write a one line inheriting wrapper class for it.

Comment: This is the integration point, which cannot be unit tested. You can unit test that part of your application that uses this. To give a good answer for that part, I would need to see the part of your code that calls this method.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is not being sealed a prerequisite?  can't i completely encapsulate the RasterCodecs class and just forward the interface methods on to the RasterCodecs class?

Comment: When it's sealed you'll have to write the pass-through code for each member. Unsealed it's automatic through inheritance.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes. so sealed isn't a requirement because as i mentioned.  you can just encapsulate everything and pass it through.  So it's still unit testable.  Less friendly than inheriting from RasterCodecs, but still doable.

Comment: What would be the tests (like the english description of them) that you'd like to write covering the `LoadImage` method above?

Comment: it would just be verifying a call to LoadImages occurred.  because you'll mock out all the other information for any tests that use LoadImages

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio do you use? If you have VS Enterprise you can use Microsoft Fakes to test this. Alternatively, you have to do what Henk suggests and wrap their class with your own, purely to test YOUR logic.